# Yii2 textinput() e httml::submitButton em uma mesma linha

Tags: html, bootstrap-3, yii

Preciso de um exemplo em Yii2 que me permita colocar alguns submitButton e textinput() em uma mesma linha , conforme o exemplo abaixo:

[image: Exemplo da linha]

parte do meu código que monta os botões :

```
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Voltar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'voltar','style' => 'width:78px']) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Atualizar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'atualizar','style' => 'width:80px']) ?>
    <?= Html::Button(Yii::t('app','Apagar'), ['id'=>'btn-confirm','class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'name' => 'apagar','style' => 'width:78px','disabled'=>$desabilitaAPAGA]) ?>
    <?php
    if($habilitaLIGA)
        echo Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Ativar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'ativar','style' => 'width:78px']);
    ?>
    <?php
    if($habilitaDESLIGA)
        echo Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Desativar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'desativar', 'style' => 'width:80px']);
    ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Gráfico'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'grafico','style' => 'width:80px']) ?>
```

Fico no aguardo de um exemplo que me ajude.

Comment: E como ficam os seus botões?

Comment: Textinput e botão grava ficam na linha de baixo, com a inserção deste código abaixo:

Comment: <div class="input-group">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'raw_data')->textInput(['style'=>'width:100px']);?>
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Grava'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'grava','style' => 'width:80px']) ?>
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar cada controle dentro de uma `div` e alinhá-las à esquerda
bem como definir o seu tamanho e o espaço que terá entre a outra.
Por exemplo:

```
<div  style="float:left; margin-left: 10px; width: 100px"> 
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Voltar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'voltar','style' => 'width:78px']) ?>
</div>
<div  style="float:left; margin-left: 10px; width: 100px"> 
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Atualizar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'atualizar','style' => 'width:80px']) ?>
</div>
<div  style="float:left; margin-left: 10px; width: 100px"> 
   <?= Html::Button(Yii::t('app','Apagar'), ['id'=>'btn-confirm','class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'name' => 'apagar','style' => 'width:78px','disabled'=>$desabilitaAPAGA])
</div>
```

Pode também criar uma definição especifica dentro do css para a classe que irá usar no botão, dai não precisará repetir as definições como width, margin-left, margin-right, float, etc...

Espero ter ajudado.